# Gradient systems and limit sets

Tags: dynamical-systems

Suppose we have an autonomous ode $$\dot{x} = f(x)$$ which corresponds to a $\underline{gradient-like}$ dynamical system, $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$. Is it true that the set of initial conditions that have in their limit set an unstable fixed point (i.e fixed point whose Jacobian has an eigenvalue with positive real part) is measure zero? Thanks

Comment: By a *gradient* system, I assume that you mean that $f$ arises as the gradient of some function $g:{\mathbb R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$, ie. $f=\nabla g$. So, is the Lorenz system a gradient system?

Comment: Yes that's right. Lorenz is not. But this is not my question... For example in Lorenz is not measure zero. I am asking if it is in gradient systems. Thanks

Comment: No. Take $\dot x=x$, this is a gradient system with potential $x^2/2$, and for *any* initial condition its $\alpha$-limit set is the unstable equilibrium $\hat{x}=0$, or am I missing something in your questions?

Comment: I consider unstable, a fixed point whose Jacobian has an eigenvalue with positive real part (inside parenthesis)